# Drupal : Gateway timeout error from proxy server

Tags: php, http, drupal, drupal-7, http-status-code-504

I was recently developed a drupal site for a client who lives in HongKong. The site worked perfectly (is still functional when I access it)
But after deploying it for demo, the client compalained that the site wasnt working and constantly getting a 504 Gateway timeout error.
Apparently the client was on a proxy server (and I'm guessing the problem is due to that factor).
Does anyone know of such problem?? And, of course, the way to fix it?

P.S.

The site is built on Drupal 7.14

This is a screenshot that the client sent me

(The server, while acting as a gateway or a proxy, did not receive a time response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to complete the request)
[image: This is a screenshot that the client sent me]

Update::

On further investigating with the client, He told me that

- The site first worked fine until he logged in as admin and added content.
- The timeout error showed when submitting the content form.
- After the error, no other page of the site would open.
- The site did function when he tried after waiting for a while (he did not account the time he waited)

UPDATE ::

ON checking the error log on the server, I found a bunch of "Page not found errors". But the weird thing is it was looking for a 406 page (for unacceptable header). Any idea why??

```
[Mon Sep 30 16:45:30 2013] [error] [client 110.44.113.254] File does not exist: /home/ekmauka/public_html/404.shtml
[Mon Sep 30 16:45:30 2013] [error] [client 110.44.113.254] File does not exist: /home/ekmauka/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Sep 30 16:45:29 2013] [error] [client 110.44.113.254] File does not exist: /home/ekmauka/public_html/404.shtml
[Mon Sep 30 16:45:29 2013] [error] [client 110.44.113.254] File does not exist: /home/ekmauka/public_html/demo
[Mon Sep 30 16:31:17 2013] [error] [client 110.44.113.254] File does not exist: /home/ekmauka/public_html/406.shtml, referer: http://ekmauka.com/ekmauka/
[Mon Sep 30 16:20:40 2013] [error] [client 110.44.113.254] File does not exist: /home/ekmauka/public_html/406.shtml, referer: http://ekmauka.com/ekmauka/content/mongolian-heart-live-hongkong-2012
[Mon Sep 30 16:20:13 2013] [error] [client 110.44.113.254] File does not exist: /home/ekmauka/public_html/406.shtml, referer: http://ekmauka.com/ekmauka/node/22/edit
```

Comment: How did you confirm that this is actually caused by Drupal?

Comment: Ask the client whether he is using a proxy server! That way, you do not have to speculate whether the client is using a proxy server.

Comment: The client sent me the screenshot that i just updated. (plus the cleint doesnt even know what a proxy server is)

Comment: @Oswald Check the updates.

Comment: @aayushshrestha If site works for you - this error is not caused by Drupal. It is a very well tested CMS.

Comment: @aayushshrestha Can he access the front page of the site?

Comment: @user4035 at first, yes. But once he logs in and makes a change and then saves it, the change occurs nonetheless, but site will stop working. No other pages would function after this.

Comment: @user4035 I built another site for the same client (on core php, no CMS). No problems occured in that site and is still functional. That is the only reason I thought it had something to do with drupal because the other site is also hosted on the same server and it works totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

- 406 problem may be caused by different localisation maybe? or something is modifying the header in custom code. do you use varnish?
- I was testing your site for a while and found out that this page http://ekmauka.com/ekmauka/content/mongolian-heart-live-hongkong-2012 takes 25 seconds to load, so look on slowqueries, optimize performance as much as you can, turn on caching and repeat tests. after that you could try to add more time to timeouts on your nginx/apache and also add more memory to php processes - 128M should be enough for your site.